# How to link UIButton in the storyboard after it has been created programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created an UIImageView and UIButton programmatically to setup constraints and I am not sure how to add this to my storyboard. I want the UIImageView and UIButton to show up on the storyboard after it has been created programmatically. How do I go about this? I'm new to swift so sorry if it's really simple.

I tried adding an @IBOutlet from the storyboard before adding in the constraints and modifying its text/image but it doesn't work.

```
class LaunchViewController: UIViewController {

    let logoImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        let logoImage = UIImage(named: "logo")
        imageView.image = logoImage
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()

    let signUpButton: UIButton = {
        let signUpButton = UIButton.init(type: .system)
        signUpButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 2, height: 20)
        signUpButton.setTitle("Sign Up.", for: .normal)
        signUpButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        signUpButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return signUpButton
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.addSubview(logoImageView)
        view.addSubview(signUpButton)
        setUpLayout()

    }

    @objc func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton!){
        print("..")
    }

    private func setUpLayout(){

        logoImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        logoImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        logoImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 220).isActive = true
        logoImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

        signUpButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: logoImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 300).isActive = true
        signUpButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor,constant: 250).isActive = true
        signUpButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        signUpButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }   
}
```

I get the expected result programmatically but I need to add it to the storyboard to perform segues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For storybard link declare like

```
@IBOutlet weak var logoImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!
```

Then add the items inside the storyboard and link them to above vars

BTW you don't have to use storbaord to perform a segue you can use `present`/`push` programmatically

Comment: I tried this but would it be possible to modify contents after declaring IBOutlets. For example I tried adding an image in the UIImageView programmatically (logoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "logo"))  after linking the IBOutlet but it didn't work.

Comment: why not set it in storyboard also ? did you tried it inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never tried adding it inside viewDidLoad! Sounds like a simple mistake.